# How to make useRef not null when creating component with Suspense

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm sort of stuck on how to implement this.

I'm rendering a map and I need to `useRef` to pass the element to the map when it is created.

The first thing that has to happen is the source file needs to download and then the `mapkit` class is available to use. I use suspense to solve this:

```
<Suspense fallback={<MapFallback />}>
  <InternalMap {...props}></InternalMap>
</Suspense>
```

What's really nice about this is `InternalMap` throws a promise when `mapkit` is not ready so the fallback is shown, and inside `InternalMap` I can assume `mapkit` is defined. Then inside `InternalMap` I have:

```
const mapDivRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

// This does not work because mapDivref.current is null, unless I decide to
//  put it inside of a useEffeect, at which point I have to verify it's created.
const map = new mapkit.Map(mapDivRef.current, options);


return (
  <div ref={mapRef} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
    {children}       
  </div>
);
```

The problem here is that I need to use `useEffect` to create my map because `mapDivRef` is `null` until the render occurs. Is there any way to define the `mapDivRef.current` before render or throw an error so the suspense fallback happens? The problem I'm trying to solve is 1/5 of my code is `if (!map) return ...`. I figured suspense would help with this as it did with the initial loading of `mapkit`. I know `mapkit` is now defined if my component is rendered. I'm trying to do the same with `map` now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly we should not create any instances inside a functional component directly as it will be created on each and every re-render.

Refs are assigned a value after initial render. Your approach to use `useEffect` to create `map` instance is correct.

To use map instance properly, do the following:

- maintain a state say `map`
- create the map instance in useEffect and save it in `map` state
- pass the map instance as a render prop which then renders a child component which can have all your logic `if (!map) return ...` etc.

**InternalMap Component**

```js
const InternalMap = props => {
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);

  const myRef = useRef(null);
  console.log(myRef.current);

  useEffect(() => {
    const myMap = new mapkit.Map(mapDivRef.current, options);
    setMap(myMap);
  }, []);

  return <div ref={mapRef} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
    {props.children(map)}
  </div>;
};
```

**Usage:**

```js
<Suspense fallback={<MapFallback />}>
  <InternalMap>
    {map => <ChildComponent {...props} map={map} />}  
  </InternalMap>
</Suspense>
```

Comment: I really wanted to do this where map was always defined because of suspense... but I just don't think it's possible since the container isn't defined yet.